# How to achieve full consistency between read (query) model and write(command) model in axon

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I have 2 spring-boot services acting as command and query as below.

1. Command-Service: Responsible for handling commands, events, maintaining aggregate's state and storing data into database.
2. Query-Service: Responsible for handling queries in order to fetch data from database.

Please note that both services are sharing the same instance of axon-server and also the same databse(in this case it is ElsaticSearch).

My UI is designed in such a way that when user submits the form to create data, an ajax call happens, which in turn performs 2 rest calls in below order:

1. First call is a post request, which goes to Command-Service, which performs below:

   - Creates a CreateDataCommand object with formdata and fires the same as below:

   ```
   org.axonframework.commandhandling.gateway.CommandGateway.sendAndWait(CreateDataCommand);
   ```

   - The CreateDataCommand is handled in the aggregate which fires DataCreatedEvent:

   ```
   @CommandHandler
   private DataAggregate(CreateDataCommand createDataCommand  ) {
      AggregateLifecycle.apply(new  DataCreatedEvent ());
   }
   ```

   - DataCreatedEvent is handled at 2 places,

     1. In the Aggregate itself, where the Aggregate updates it's state:

     ```
     @EventSourcingHandler
     private void on(AppCreatedEvent appCreatedEvent) {
        // updated aggregate's state
     }
     ```

     2. In the Projection, Which saves data into the database.

     ```
     @EventHandler
     private void on(AppCreatedEvent appCreatedEvent) {
       // Saves data to database.
     }
     ```
2. Upon sucessful execution of above, the ajax immediately sends a get request to Query-Service which performs below:

   - Fires  GetDataQuery query as below:

     ```
     org.axonframework.queryhandling.QueryGateway.query(GetDataQuery, ResponseType);
     ```
   - The  GetDataQuery is handled to fetch data from database as below:

     ```
     @QueryHandler
     List<Data> getData(GetDataQuery getDataQuery){
       // hits the databse and returns data.
     }
     ```

**Problem**:
Even though the data is being saved into the database by Command-Service, the call to Query-Service is triggred and it always returns empty list. On second call onwards it returns the correct data. This is happening because Query-Service hits the database before Command-Service finishes creating data in database.

The ajax script:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "directs to Command-Service to save data",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 60000,
        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
        success: data => {
            setTimeout(() => location.replace("url of query-service"), 1000);
        }
});
```

Can someone please help me in achieving the full consistency or find a way to eradicate the inconsistency which is occurring on account of above phenomenon.

Comment: I feel this issue is a duplicate of this question you've posted rohit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045477/how-to-make-command-to-wait-until-all-events-triggered-against-it-are-completed
It's better to keep a single question out there to maintain focus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make command to wait until all events triggered against it are completed successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045477/how-to-make-command-to-wait-until-all-events-triggered-against-it-are-completed)